# Doxygen custom cross-reference page shows namespace instead of class names (PHP)

Tags: php, doxygen

I have namespaced PHP classes documented as such:

```
<?php 
namespace container;

/**
 * Description of Stuff
 * 
 * \xrefitem wpaction "Actions" "Actions Wordpress" init
 */
 class Stuff {}
```

Other example:

```
<?php
namespace container;

/**
 * Description of Things
 *
 * \xrefitem wpaction "Actions" "Actions Wordpress" admin
 */
class Things {}
```

They are cross-referenced in the page defined as such:

```
/**
 * \page wpaction Wordpress actions
 *
 * All Wordpress actions used by ACME software.
 */
```

The problem is that, instead of class names, only the `container` namespace appears in the Doxygen generated cross-reference page:

[image]

`container\Stuff` and `container\Things` should appear instead.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

(I use ALIASES to shorten calls to `\xrefitem` in production code, but I omitted it in this test case to narrow down the problem.)

Comment: Looks like a bug, please submit a bug report here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen